# Upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.04.1

Tags: upgrade

Will I be given an option to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.1 from 14.04 when I bootup from a cd or usb drive? Or do I need to do a complete new install?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe it's just a normal update. I did a fresh install from a 14.04 disk the day before .1 was released and the next day, after an update I had 14.04.1

Answer (score 1):

If you have been doing regular updates, you may already have 14.04.1.

check $`lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 0):

If you have 14.04 and you have been allowing it to install all the updates, you will already have all the updates included in 14.04.1.

The "point releases" like this are a way of bundling all the updates that have been released so far so that people installing 14.04 "fresh" (eg from a DVD) won't need to download so many updates immediately after installation.  It may also allow a smoother installation process because the version being installed will benefit from any new hardware support in those updates.

But if you already have a 14.04 system you'll already have those updates.

Answer (score 0):

If `lsb_release -a` shows that you are running 14.04 try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade && sudo shutdown -r now`

After the reboot you should be running Ubuntu 14.04.1